# Facebook OAuth 2.0 mechanism does not always redirect to redirect_uri when pressing cancel

Tags: facebook, redirect, oauth-2.0

I have an issue with the Facebook OAuth 2.0 mechanism. In principle all is working well, except for one thing: when a user is redirected to the page where he should authorize/permit the app but is clicking 'Cancel', about half of the time he is redirected to the page I specified in the redirect_uri (correct behaviour - so I redirect him to a page explaining why we need the permissions) and about half the time he is ending up on the FB homepage (wrong behaviour). I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. This is roughly what I am doing:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
   FB.init({
       appId      : <appid>, // App ID
       channelUrl : 'http://www.mydomain.com/channel.html', // Channel File
       status     : true, // check login status
       cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
       oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
       xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
   });

   // Additional initialization code here
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
   {
       //console.log('getLoginStatus response: ',response);
       if (response.authResponse) 
       {
           //user is already logged in and connected
           top.location.href='http://apps.facebook.com/<appname>';
       }
       else
       {
           //app is not authorized or user is logged out
           var redirectURL = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id='+client_id+'&scope='+scope+'&redirect_uri='+encodeURIComponent('http://apps.facebook.com/<appname>')+'&response_type=token';
           top.location.href = redirectURL;
       }
   });
};
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? As said in the opposite case, where the user does accept to authorize the app al works just fine. I am still working in sandbox mode and have not yet bought an SSL certificate which is why I am still referring everywhere to http instead of https.

Thanks!

P.S. This strange behaviour never happens when the user clicks 'Don\'t allow' when asking for optional permissions the following times the user accesses my app. For example, the user logs in for the first time and authorizes the app, but does not allow for the optional permissions. Facebook then redirects him to the redirect_uri and gives me an access_token, so I redirect the user to the app (so far so good). The next time when the user accesses the app, I detect that he has authorized the app, but that I don't have all the optional permissions I want, so I redirect him again to the OAuth 2.0 mechanism. This time the user AGAIN doesn't allow the optional permissions and Facebook ALWAYS redirects the user to the redirect_uri which is the expected behaviour.

Comment: I'm starting to believe this is a feature and not a bug... I'm seeing the same behaviour with another well-known app. Also when I set the 'Enhanced Auth Dialog' to disabled in the App settings, then the first time you ask for permissions the buttons are named 'Allow' and 'Don't allow', but the second time you go there they are called 'Allow' and 'Leave App'. This would explain the behaviour... Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Yes, it's to avoid people showing the popup again and again. The first time you get "cancel" but next times you get a "leave app" button